# GCC: Building cross-compiler for ARM - pthread.h not found

Tags: gcc, pthreads, cross-compiling, gnu

Using a Ubuntu 12.04 host, I carefully followed this SO answer here ([Recipe for Compiling Binutils and GCC Together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726042/recipe-for-compiling-binutils-gcc-together)) to build GCC and binutils in one tree with all of their dependencies.

Here is the configure line I am doing inside my build directory:

```
    ../gcc-4.9.0/configure --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/mint/cross-arm --disable-werror
```

The Makefile configures correctly and afterwards I run:

```
    sudo make -j8
```

I get into the compilation process for some time then eventually it errors out here:

```
    In file included from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/gthr.h:148:0,
             from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/libgcov-interface.c:27:
./gthr-default.h:35:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
#include <pthread.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [_gcov_flush.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/gthr.h:148:0,
             from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/libgcov-interface.c:27:
./gthr-default.h:35:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
#include <pthread.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [_gcov_execlp.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/gthr.h:148:0,
             from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/libgcov-interface.c:27:
./gthr-default.h:35:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
#include <pthread.h>
                 ^
In file included from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/gthr.h:148:0,
             from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/libgcov-interface.c:27:
./gthr-default.h:35:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
#include <pthread.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: compilation terminated.
*** [_gcov_fork.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_gcov_execl.o] Error 1
In file included from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/gthr.h:148:0,
             from ../../../gcc-4.9.0/libgcc/libgcov-interface.c:27:
./gthr-default.h:35:21: fatal error: pthread.h: No such file or directory
#include <pthread.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [_gcov_execle.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mint/Workspaces/src/build/arm-linux-gnueabi/libgcc'
make[1]: *** [all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mint/Workspaces/src/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Am I missing a certain dependency that is preventing this build?

P.S. I installed 'build-essential' via apt-get before the build.

Comment: What about letting for example [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) making this work for you?

Comment: Is it pretty painless?

Comment: So far I didn't experienced any problems. BR provides several ways to get a toolcahin. Just read [this](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_cross_compilation_toolchain) portion of documentation and try the way, that best suits your needs. In the most cases I use external toolchain, it saves time, when I need to recompile the whole rootfs.

Comment: how will anyone know know to maintain buildroot or replace it without learning. Its like not going to math class because calculators exist...

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests some issue with the C library.

For building the GCC compiler, you need prebuilt binutils + prebuilt C library.

In case of cross compiler, one possible route is :

1. Ensure that you have prebuilt binutils (cross compile build)
2. Cross compile GCC :
   Add Configure option --without-headers. Now compile (see make targets in the link below)
3. Compile your C library and point to it when compiling your program for the target

See some instructions for cross-compiling gcc here [GCC Cross Compiling](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler). Then "install" the appropriate C library (glibc / newlib).

Also, (if you are not already doing it) it may be worthwhile to ensure that the --prefix for bintutils and the gcc cross compile build are the same location.

Comment: If you take a look at the linked SO answer, I have symlinked all of GCC's dependencies inside the gcc-4.9.0/ dir, I run ./configure like shown above and what I expect is everything to be built with these options.

Is this not a recommended way to do this?

Comment: The SO answer does not directly relate with a cross-compiler build. Although keep in mind that building the binuitls + gcc in a common dir source tree is orthogonal to whether you are building a cross compiler or not. The problem at hand is because of another dependency of the whole cross-compilation setup = which is C library.

Comment: I see. I've read up on the link you provided. If I compiled as specified, it would return a naked compiler where a simple import of stdio.h would crash it. How would I install the C library post compilation?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now for the C library, you can either use newlib/glibc. Configuring and compiling them should be very straightforward. Its been a while since I did a cross compiler build, so cannot give you the configure command etc right away.

Comment: I followed directions and after installing binutils, gcc fails with the same pthread error on `make all-target-libgcc`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have chosen to not use disable-threads for GCC configure ?

Comment: I had no clue that option existed. I'll have to try it.